# Error in sql coding

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL query in Access and I get this error message:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that
>   is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

The query:

```
select* into #temp from mfr
union
select* from polmfr
select rfno,
sum(ppic) as ppic, 
sum(pcrt) as pcrt 
from #temp 
group by rfno

SELECT MFR.RFNO,
Sum([MFR]![THAN]) AS THAN, 
Sum([MFR]![CRT]) AS CRT, 
Sum([MFR]![GPCS]) AS GPCS, 
Sum([MFR]![RCRT]) AS RCRT, 
Sum([MFR]![GCRT]) AS GCRT, 
Sum([MFR]![GFPCS]) AS GFPCS,
Sum([MFR]![GFCRT]) AS GFCRT,
Sum([MFR]![PPIC]) AS PPIC, 
Sum([MFR]![PCRT]) AS PCRT, 
Sum([MFR]![KP]) AS KP, 
Sum([MFR]![KPCRT]) AS KPCRT, 
Sum([MFR]![GPCS])-(Sum([MFR]![GFPCS])) AS GKP, [GCRT]/Sum(IIf([MFR]![GCRT]>0,[MFR]!        [RCRT],0)) AS [G%], 
Sum(IIf([MFR]![GCRT]>0,[MFR]![GFCRT],0))/[GCRT] AS [RB%], [GFCRT]/[RCRT] AS [GF%],   [THAN]/[CRT] AS [SIZE], [PCRT]/Sum(IIf([MFR]![PCRT]>0,[MFR]![RCRT],0)) AS [P%], 
FROM MFR
group by rfno
ORDER BY MFR.RFNO;
```

Comment: pretty clear suggestion from the error message. What is your question?

Comment: break it down into sections, comment out portions and find where it starts/stops working.

Comment: Are you sure this is access? why are you using a table name starting with #? I would expect to see that in SQL Server.

Comment: I M VERY FRESH IN ALL THIS AND NOT LEARNED ANY LANGUAGE THIS ALL I DO IT ON MY OWN

Comment: It won't help to shout at people who might otherwise be inclined to help you. Try to take their advice and edit your question to better explain your problem.

Comment: it could be that you don't have a space in between `SELECT` and `*` .... Your syntax: `SELECT*` .. Proper syntax: `SELECT *` ? Or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: thanks for replay all